# MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT does not work: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, auto-increment

```
CREATE TABLE User (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  image_file VARCHAR(40),
  password VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Post (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  date_posted DATE NOT NULL,
  content VARCHAR(10000) NOT NULL,
  user_id INT,
  like_count INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Post_comment (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  date_commented DATE NOT NULL,
  content VARCHAR(10000) NOT NULL,
  user_id INT,
  like_count INT NOT NULL,
  post_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);  

CREATE TABLE post_liked_by (
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  post_id int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id,post_id)
);

CREATE TABLE comment_liked_by (
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  comment_id int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id,comment_id)
);

ALTER TABLE User AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE Post
ADD FOREIGN KEY(user_id)
REFERENCES User(id)
ON DELETE SET NULL;

ALTER TABLE Post_comment
ADD FOREIGN KEY(user_id)
REFERENCES User(id)
ON DELETE SET NULL;

ALTER TABLE Post_comment
ADD FOREIGN KEY(post_id)
REFERENCES User(id)
ON DELETE SET NULL;

INSERT INTO User (username, email, password) VALUES ('egname', 'eg@eg.com', 'egpassword')
```

This code gives the error **ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value** when I try to insert into the User table but I am not really sure why. I thought by setting AUTO_INCREMENT for the id field the default value would be 1? Could it be a problem with the configuration of my code editor? I am using PopSQL btw.

It works fine when I specify a value for id but I need it to increment automatically each time I insert a new data.

For context I am trying to build a simple project something like a clone of facebook. Tqvm in advance.

Comment: You already posted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64174181/mysql-auto-increment-not-working-field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value Why did you delete the original instead of improving it?

Comment: Errm sorry I am not really sure why but it was made to be not accepting new answers so I posted a new one with new edits to make it better. apologies for any inconveniences caused as I am relatively new to asking in stackoverflow.